# On mobile, card images on bootstrap tabs extends past the right edge of the screen

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I added boostrap tabs to show some card images. It was working fine until I added the images and checked it on mobile.

I"m experiencing two issues. 
1) On desktop, the images don't extend all the way to the right on the row.
2) On mobile, the images extend beyond the right edge of the screen.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/IRDX7Ijl5I

Here's my HTML:

```
    <div class="content-section-c">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2>Sample Search Results</h2>
            </div>
        <div class="tabbable">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#pane1" data-toggle="tab">APPLE<br>
                TREES
                               </a></li>
            <li><a href="#pane2" data-toggle="tab">ORANGE<br>TREES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pane3" data-toggle="tab">PEARS <br> TREES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pane4" data-toggle="tab">BANANAS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pane4" data-toggle="tab">GRAPE<br> TREES</a></li> 
                           </ul>
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="pane1" class="tab-pane active">
              <p>126 Results Founds</p>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/01_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/02_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/03_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/04_card.png"></div> 
                                                  </div>
            <div id="pane2" class="tab-pane">
            <p>75 Results Founds</p>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/05_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/06_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/07_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/08_card.png"></div> 
            </div>
            <div id="pane3" class="tab-pane">
              <p>144 Results Founds</p>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/09_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/10_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/11_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/12_card.png"></div> 
            </div>
            <div id="pane4" class="tab-pane">
              <p>170 Results Founds</p>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/01_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/02_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/03_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/04_card.png"></div> 
            </div>
            <div id="pane5" class="tab-pane">
              <p>256 Results Founds</p>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/01_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/02_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/03_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/04_card.png"></div> 
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.tab-content -->
        </div><!-- /.tabbable -->
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</div>
<!-- /.content-section-c -->
```

Here's my CSS:

```
    .nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover{
 border-top: none;
 border-left: none;
 border-right: none;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #e9a39c;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a:hover{
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an image that resizes itself to fit the device it's being viewed on?

You might want to add the img-responsive class to your image tag, for example:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/03_card.png">
```